# R - Make new column and fill based on cell value between two delimiter

Tags: r, dataframe

Ive got a dataframe which looks like

```
Q 1 
1234    data1
1235    data2
1236    data3
Q 2 
1237    data5
1238    data6
1239    data7
1240    data8
Q 3 
1241    data10
```

In this example the Q value corresponds to a type of header for the IDs and data below it.
I want to put all the Q values into a new column, matching the Q "header" to the respective IDs. like so

```
Q 1 1234    data1
Q 1 1235    data2
Q 1 1236    data3
Q 2 1237    data5
Q 2 1238    data6
Q 2 1239    data7
Q 2 1240    data8
Q 3 1241    data10
```

Example

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 8L), .Label = c("1234", "1235", "1236", "1237","1238", "1239", "1240", "1241", "Q 1", "Q 2", "Q 3"), class = "factor"), 
V2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("", "data1", "data10", "data2", "data3","data5", "data6", "data7", "data8"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-11L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a new column (`V3`) where we copy values from `V1` and has `NA` for values which do not start with `"Q"`. We replace those `NA`s with `tidyr::fill` and remove rows from data where `V1` starts with `"Q"`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  mutate(V3 = replace(V1, !startsWith(V1, "Q"), NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(V3) %>%
  filter(!startsWith(V1, "Q"))

#    V1     V2  V3
#1 1234  data1 Q 1
#2 1235  data2 Q 1
#3 1236  data3 Q 1
#4 1237  data5 Q 2
#5 1238  data6 Q 2
#6 1239  data7 Q 2
#7 1240  data8 Q 2
#8 1241 data10 Q 3
```

---

As @camille mentioned we can also extract `"Q \\d"` from `V1` and then use `fill`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(V3 = stringr::str_extract(V1, "Q \\d")) %>%
  tidyr::fill(V3) %>%
  filter(!grepl("^Q", V1))
```

Comment: The second mutate call might be more straightforward if you just use regex to extract the `"Q \\d"` strings, since you'll get NA where that doesn't occur. Might also let you skip the first mutate

Answer (score 2):

```
subset(transform(d, Id = d$V1[which(d$V2 == "")[cumsum(d$V2 == "")]]), V2 != "")
#     V1     V2  Id
#2  1234  data1 Q 1
#3  1235  data2 Q 1
#4  1236  data3 Q 1
#6  1237  data5 Q 2
#7  1238  data6 Q 2
#8  1239  data7 Q 2
#9  1240  data8 Q 2
#11 1241 data10 Q 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rle` and `rep` to `cbind` the header to the datalines.

```
i  <- x$V2 == ""
#i <- grepl("^Q", x$V1) #Alternative
cbind(header=rep(x$V1[i], rle(i)$lengths[c(FALSE,TRUE)]), x[!i,])
#   header   V1     V2
#2     Q 1 1234  data1
#3     Q 1 1235  data2
#4     Q 1 1236  data3
#6     Q 2 1237  data5
#7     Q 2 1238  data6
#8     Q 2 1239  data7
#9     Q 2 1240  data8
#11    Q 3 1241 data10
```